# Is about 0.5 seconds of latency a usual thing in mobile gaming multi-peer networks?

Tags: android, ios, networking, bluetooth

So I have been experimenting with multi-peer networks.  Ultimately I am going to try to use different frameworks to make one that can connect devices of same os through Bluetooth and WiFi, and ones of different types through wifi.

My first shot was apple's Multi-peer Networking.  Unfortunately I got had about 0.5 seconds of delay (I didn't actually calculate this just an estimate) before even one bit of information actually got to the other device.  I am suspicious that the framework is optimized for larger and encrypted data way more then it is for 1-32 bit jobs.

I was just wondering what you guys knew about the latency of other frameworks out their, since it takes a decent chunk of time for me to learn how to use each new framework.  Is latency of about 0.5 seconds the best the industry has?

Honestly I would be happy if their was a library that was optimized to send 1 bit to each connected device every (1/60th) of a second. But I think most of these networks package up the data like its of bigger size anyways.

I sorta wish mobile devices had NFC.  Just look at systems like the 3ds that can do multi-peer multiplayer (smash-bros) with really really small latency and great accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the [MCSessionSendDataMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCSessionClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MCSessionSendDataMode) to `MCSessionSendDataUnreliable`

> MCSessionSendDataUnreliable
>   Messages to peers should be sent immediately without socket-level queueing. If a message cannot be sent immediately, it should be dropped. The order of messages is not guaranteed.
>
> This message type should be used for data that ceases to be relevant if delayed, such as real-time gaming data.

but depends how reliable you really need the data to be, but on a closed network, it should be very reliable anyway

Comment: Yeah I have been doing that with no huge advantage.